# Modify 'Normal' style in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` to write an XLSX file. A style I've created can be modified using `my_style.alignment = Alignment(vertical='top')`.

How can I apply the same change of alignment to the existing 'Normal' style?

(`openpyxl`'s documentation says "For more information about the builtin styles please refer to the [openpyxl.styles.builtins](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.styles.builtins.html#module-openpyxl.styles.builtins)" but the linked page currently does not contain any information.)

Comment: You have to iterate all cells and apply the style to each individually

Comment: I know how to apply a style to cells. The question was how to modify an existing style, e.g., how to change Normal style's colour or alignment.